# Does Windows 7 store information about the MTU of a network?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, windows-7, ping

I have the following network setup:

`[Customizable Wireless AP] ----- [Windows 7 Laptop]`

In other words, my Win7 laptop is connected to a wireless access point which I can configure.  I am using the `Wireshark` packet analyzer to monitor ping traffic.

My process is:

- Set MTU of the AP very low (500)
- Verify AP MTU has taken effect
- Start packet analyzer in Wireshark
- Use `ping www.google.com -f -l 700` to send an oversized packet

**Actual Output:**

- Ping shows `Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.`, indicating that the MTU has been observed
- Wireshark shows **no** traffic.  No ICMP messages or traffic of any king.

**Expected Output:**

- I expect ping to show `Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.`, indicating that the MTU has been observed
- I expect Wireshark to show ICMP traffic where the AP informs Win7 that the packet is too large.

**My Question:**

How is Windows discovering or remembering the MTU without the AP (seemingly) ever informing it?  Is there an MTU discovery mechanism built into Win7 that operates prior to the `ping`?

Comment: It seems likely that by the time Wireshark kicks in, Windows has already sent enough packets to determine the MTU.  (In the default configuration, Windows is fairly noisy.)  You might need to use an external analyzer to see what's going on, or at least turn Wireshark on before reconfiguring the AP.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 uses Path MTU Discovery (PMTUD) to figure out the MTU and control the fragmentation. There is a 3-bit flag field in IP header that will determine how fragmentation of a packet should be performed:

- bit 0: Reserved; must be zero
- bit 1: Don't Fragment (DF)
- bit 2: More Fragments (MF)

If the DF bit is set, then any device along the path with MTU smaller than the packet will drop it and send back an ICMP message requesting fragmentation. However, ICMP message might blocked due to security reason. Therefore you cannot see any of it.

Comment: @Adam S: Does it answer your question?